# Run Rscript through all directories in a file

Tags: r, shell, unix

I have a sample Rscript as follows :

```
library(bio3d)
s2 <- read.pdb('test.pdb',rm.alt = FALSE)
write.pdb(s2,'test_changed.pdb')
```

I want to run it through all directories which contain following files :
Sample directory

```
Folder1
test.pdb

Folder2
test.pdb
```

Desired output directory

```
Folder1
test.pdb
test_changed.pdb

Folder2
test.pdb
test_changed.pdb
```

How to run the Rscript from terminal setting directory path each time ?

Comment: You want to run this from terminal and not from inside R ?

Comment: yes,from terminal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't use R, but assuming you run one R script in Terminal like this:

```
rscript /path/to/YOURSCRIPT.R
```

then I think you want something like this to run that same script in all directories containing a file called `test.pdb`:

```
find . -name test.pdb -execdir rscript /path/to/YOURSCRIPT.R \;
```